# unexpected '=' in the code, Tried to execute two SQL queries in one php file

Tags: php, mysql

I m trying to get the existing "usercouponinhand" value from "userpaytoget" table and add it to received 'id' value as from "GET" tag. Then update it to the same "userpaytoget" table "usercouponinhand" column.

But unfortunately i see this "Unexpected =" error on the line `result = $conn->query($sql);`

The code follows:

```
<?php include('usercoupondelete.php'); ?>
<?php
$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "";

$mobile = $_SESSION['mobile'];
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM userpaytoget WHERE mobile = '$mobile' ";
result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$usercouponinhand = $row["usercouponinhand"];
$couponvalue = $_GET["id"];
$totalvalue = $couponvalue + $usercouponinhand ;

$sql2 = "UPDATE userpaytoget SET usercouponinhand = '$totalvalue', date = '$date', date2 = '$date2'
WHERE mobile = '$mobile'";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
echo  '<a href="usercoupondelete"></a>';
}
else {
echo "ERROR" . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

}
 } else {
echo "None";
} 
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: `result = $conn->query($sql);` you missed $ before result

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize your queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: can you suggest me how to avoid that

Comment: Use `PDO` [ http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ]

Comment: @HarishKolliparat I did vaguely here's a link, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Parameterize it and use the prepare/execute and you'll be good.

Comment: @NN PDO and mysqli both support prepared statements, either can be used incorrectly (as demonstrated here).

Comment: @chris85 thanks man...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `$`

It should be `$result = $conn->query($sql);`